# Trying NOT to use Out-GridView

Tags: powershell, winforms, messagebox

I use a call to `GetADUser`, which is just returning the Sam Account Name of all the users in an OU.

I'm trying to display them in a System Windows Forms Message Box but its not working.

I know I'm close, but I'm having a brain fart.  Is there a better way of doing this?  Again, I'm trying very hard to avoid using `Out-GridView`.  I'd love to have something like this:

```
UserTest1
UserTest2
UserTest3
```

I tried a couple of google searches but they were not really what I'm trying to do.  Any help would be appreciated
Thank you

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for a `ListBox` but without seeing your code we can't tell how close you are ;)

Comment: I thought of that as well but I didn't really like the look of it.  I can't really post code at this point.  Just wasn't sure if someone else already did what I'm trying to do and that is to redirect the output of get ad user to a form not using out grid view

Comment: A simple message box should be easy to do. I don't know if there's a character limit, but something like this should work: `[Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($Users, "User List", [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]"OK", [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]"Information")`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician, I know I could do this but I'm trying to only return the sam account name and not all the other stuff.

Comment: This is how I'm pulling the users back: $Users = Get-ADUser -filter * -Searchbase $OU | Select-object SamAccountName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use a WinForms [message box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox) for this:

```bash
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

# Create 20 sample user names.
# In your real code, use:
#   $users = (Get-ADUser -filter * -Searchbase $OU).SamAccountName
$users = 1..20 | ForEach-Object { "user" + $_ }

# Display a message box with each username on its own line.
[Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(
  $users -join "`n",
  'Title',       # window title
  'OKCancel',    # buttons
  'Information'  # icon
)
```

Note that this is only suitable for a *limited* number of usernames, namely as many as will fit on your screen *at once*, excluding the space needed to display the title bar and the button(s).
If there are too many, not all will be visible, and the button(s) won't show.

To avoid this problem, you'd need to create a custom form with a (scrollable) list box.

Comment: I got it working using a list box.  Thanks for everyone's help!  Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Searchbase $Var1 | Where-Object {$__.name -notlike
    "$var2*"} | ForEach-Object{[void]$Var3.Items.Add($_.SamAccountName)}
```

Hope this will help someone else